# Removing HTML Text in RSS Description

Tags: xcode, rss, mobile-application, yahoo-pipes

I already have created a Yahoo pipe (http://pipes.yahoo.com/adudley/movies) that pulls from a website RSS feed to display movie times, pictures, etc.  However, when looking at the Yahoo generated RSS for my pipe, I still get HTML text in the description part of the RSS feed.  Is there any way to take this out or it not be visible where it will only contain the actual movie description instead of having HTML in there as well?  I am trying to create a simple test run iOS mobile app in Xcode that pulls the description from the RSS feed, but right now it displays the HTML text as well.  I do not want that HTML to be seen on the app.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Do you want to simply delete the description of the RSS items, or something more?

Comment: Sorry. I am trying to remove the HTML tags that come before the RSS description. I only want the actual description without the tags in front of it.